# Can't boot into graphical desktop after installing SELinux

Tags: selinux

I have a problem trying to get gui environment to bootup after installing selinux. Selinux does work when I  boot up but it doesn't boot up in gui environment; in other words, the only way I can use Ubuntu GUI environment is by recovery boot, but it disables selinux when I do that. I also installed gdm to try to use the ctrl+alt+f1 method and the alt+f2 method to enter the login screen in text to run gdm by text. It doesn't work. I was wondering what i am doing wrong. I am a noob at Linux for I have been using it for about two years (If you count Android) now. Is this a bug? Or is this have to indirectly do with me as a user making it seem like a bug? Here is my grub.cfg file. I did try to replace selinux with apparmor; but it didn't work right that might be why you see apparmor in there. I decided to go back to selinux because it seems to offer more security than apparmor. When I tried to reinstall apparmor it said something like this...

```
root@ubuntu~/ aa-status
apparmor module is loaded.
apparmor filesystem is not mounted.
```

I tried to install a debian package and I have  the file inside my downloads files it is called `selinux-utils_2.0.96-1_i386.deb` I think that is what probably jacked it up anyway; but, I heard that Ubuntu stopped supporting selinux so that is why i used that one after hearing about the issues and bugs with selinux getting to work right. But, I was willing to take the risk.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="security=selinux selinux=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="  apparmor=1 security=apparmor"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

This is what pops up when I can finally use gui in failsafe mode in recovery in the terminal.

```
root@ubuntu:~# sestatus
SELinux status: disabled
root@ubuntu:~# setenforce 1
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Anything will be helpful.

PS

I am interested in computer programming and I am eager to learn java, python, C++ and etc. I would love to contribute software to the open source community especially to future Ubuntu projects. I was wondering on what seL4 micro-kernel can do for Ubuntu such as make a new version "selinux" better than the original making a Linux system mathematically hack proof.

Comment: For what it's worth, most people who even use CentOS disable SELinux or set it to Permissive mode (it's a huge headache)

Comment: If you want to try selinux use Fedora or RHEL (Centos, Scientific). Most people whoe use Centos leave selinux enabled, especially on production servers. Fedora has great tools, both graphical and command line, to debug selinux. I have not seen selinux run successfully on Ubuntu in several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every probability like how a computer plays chess; I used this solution and it worked.

1.root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install lxdm

I booted up in a graphical environment, and I tried sestatus command in terminal and it said it was working; however my wifi stopped connecting even though I used iwconfig it said it wasn't connected to anything. I am using an Asus 900ha mini netbook pc. Think like a computer to fix a computer is what I learned today. Try every possible solution even if it is a lot  and I promise you most likely will fix the problem!